# Find exactly what php files are responsible for each php process

Tags: php

I have a WordPress website hosted on a shared Red Hat 4.4.7-18 Linux box and from time to time I get huge memory and I/O spikes exceeding my allowed memory limit making my website unresponsive.

I have cPanel installed but there is no way I can find out exactly what process is causing this but only seeing those spikes.

I think this is being caused by one of my plugins and would really want to know which of them does that. I have 15+ plugin installed so enabling/disabling each one and monitoring if the issue still exists it's not an option as this apparently happens randomly.

I can SSH into my box and I would like to know if there is a way I can find what php file is behind each of the PHP processes I see either when running ps -aux | less or when I visit the PHP Processes option from my cpanel.

[image]

Knowing this information I could easily identify what plugin/script is causing those memories and I/O spikes.

Comment: This is probably a good question for https://serverfault.com/

Comment: I would say proper server monitoring solution, such as New Relic, would probably help you figure it out faster than anything on WP side.